# Nested virtualization: run RHEVH inside KVM

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kvm, nested-virtualization, rhev

I have laptop with 16GB RAM, trying to install Red Hat Enterprise Virtualization Hypervisor 3.3 on Virtual Machine Manager (KVM) based guest, but it gives error "Virtualization Hardware not found".

What's possible solution for this error?
Like in OracleVM box there is a option to enable support for Virtualization for guest machine? Is there anything like same in Virtual Machine Manager?

Is it possible to test RHEV 3.3 on any of the virtualization like KVM, OracleVM box or VMWare Workstation 10?

Comment: Although I don't know either RHEVH or KVM, it's generally impossible to use a VM as a VM host. That's because the virtualization software on the host needs direct access to hardware resources. And that's impossible on VMs. As I recall, it is possible to use VMware and VirtualBox VMs as OpenVZ hosts, but that's not saying much ;)

Comment: @mirimir That's called “nested virtualization”, and it is possible with some combinations of VM software — generally only with recent high-end processors that provide some hardware features that make it easier.

Comment: Nested KVM [is possible](http://www.rdoxenham.com/?p=275), so RHEV in KVM might be possible. The [3.3 manual](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Virtualization/3.3/html/Installation_Guide/CPU_Requirements.html) doesn't mention that possibility: it only lists physical CPU models as possible hosts. There isn't an explicit sentence [“must be installed on a physical server”](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Virtualization/3.0/html/Installation_Guide/sect-Installation_Guide-Installing_the_PRODUCT_Hypervisor.html) in 3.0 though.

Comment: Nested virtualization is a rare need. [What do you want it for?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Gilles Thank you very much for your link, but when I am adding module `kvm-intel` with `nested` module loaded `grub2` it returns the following error: FATAL: Error inserting kvm_intel (/lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.centos.plus.x86_64/kernel/arch/x86/kvm/kvm-intel.ko): Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg) Please can you help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible run rhev 3.3 into a kvm virtualized machine. You have to enable cpu virtualization options (from BIOS), and then install RHEL as Operating System. Then, once installed RHEL, you have to install RHEV 3.3 (if your private channels are enable and whole).

But, if you want to use KVM as hypervisor, it is not possible, for the reasons before mentioned.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure nesting on the laptop before you try to run a hypervisor inside a VM. In any case, this is not going to be a very fast or anywhere production worthy setup. Good enough for testing and demos though