# RHEV cannot start inside Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, kvm, virtualization, nested-virtualization, rhev

While installing RHEV Hypervisor 3.3 on Oracle VirtualBox I am getting following message:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine RhevH1
VT-x is used by another hypervisor.
(VERR_VMX__IN_VMX_ROOT_MODE).
VirtualBox Can't operate in VMX root mode. Please disable the KVM
kernel extension, recompile your kernel and reboot
(VERR_VMX_IN_VMX_ROOT_MODE).
```

What are the possible solutions are there for this?

Comment: This is basically the same question as <http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136167/error-virtualization-hardware-not-found-on-kvm>. You can't run VMs on VMs. That's what the error about VT-x is telling you :)

Comment: No both are different on is for Virtual Machine Manager and another is for Oracle VM Box.

Comment: OK, they're not identical. But I guarantee that you'll get more or less the same error trying to run RHEV on any sort of VM.

Answer (score 0):

[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032) does not support running any kind of native virtualization software inside it (VirtualBox itself, KVM/RHEV, Hyper-V, ESX, Xen in full virtualization mode, …).

Run RHEV directly on the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

RHEV hypervisor can run nested under kvm or vmware, but vbox doesn't support nesting, and willnot expose virtual functions inside the VM. Nothing to do with RHEV, this is a vbox limitation.